# How to change border style of CGRect in Swift2?

Tags: ios, swift2, cgrect

I'm learning Swift and my designer has given me a screen like this.

[image]

I am facing problem in how to change the border style of total credits `CGRect` in this dashed form.

My code is:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    let promobox =  UIView()

    promobox.frame = CGRectMake(16, promotextfield.frame.minY + 180, self.view.frame.width - 32, 60)
    promobox.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2).CGColor
    promobox.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    promobox.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.2).CGColor

    //background color of box
    self.view.addSubview(promobox)
}
```

Comment: Have you ever work in objective-c?? (can you convert objective-c code to swift?)

Comment: Did you try with my code? @Sonika Sood

Comment: yes it worked @Abhinav

Comment: Could you please accept my answer for the benefit of others. @SonikaSood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do this:

```
let promobox =  UIView()

promobox.frame = CGRectMake(16, 50, self.view.frame.width - 32, 60)
promobox.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
promobox.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
promobox.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.2).CGColor

let border = CAShapeLayer.init()
border.frame = promobox.bounds
border.path = UIBezierPath(rect: border.frame).CGPath
border.lineWidth = 2
border.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2).CGColor
border.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
border.lineDashPattern = [4, 6]
promobox.layer.addSublayer(border)
```

Play with `lineDashPattern` to meet your designer's expectations.